# Predict out of sample R2 with stats model

Tags: python, statsmodels

This is my code to train my model an check in sample statistics

```
  #OLS statsmodels: Train the model 
    model = sm.OLS(Ytrain, Xtrain)
    results = model.fit()

    #In of Sample Statistics + residuals
    InY_Prediction = results.predict(Xtrain)
    InR2 = results.rsquared
    InAdjR2 = results.rsquared_adj
    InResiduals = Ytrain-InY_Prediction
    #print(results.summary())
```

I am trying to have the R2 like in my first code for out of sample data

```
#Out of Sample Statistics + residuals
OutY_Predicted = results.predict(Xtest)
```

How can I have the R2 for the out of sample regression?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I have the R2 for the out of sample regression

Answer (score 0):

By definition rsquared is the squared correlation coefficient of your dependent variable (say ytest) and the fitted values (OutY_Predicted). So a way to get the usual rsquared is:

```
OutY_Predicted = results.predict(Xtest)
rsquared = ytest.corr(OutY_Predicted)**2
```